# What is the variable for the human readable name of the node type?

Tags: 7

In my node.tpl I have added `<?php print $type; ?>`. This gives me the machine name of the node type e.g. blog_entry. What do I use to get the human readable form e.g. Blog entry?

Edit (Here is my current code)

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted"><div class="submitted-type submitted-item"><?php print $type; ?></div><div class="submitted-author submitted-item"><?php print $name; ?></div><div class="submitted-date submitted-item"><?php print $date; ?></div><div class="submitted-comments submitted-item"><?php print $comment_count; ?></div></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`node_type_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_load/7) function to load up the node type object, and then extract the name:

```
$type_obj = node_type_load($type);
$name = $type_obj->name;
```

You can integrate with your current code like so:

```
<?php
  $type_obj = node_type_load($type);
  $human_readable_type = $type_obj->name;
?>

<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <div class="submitted-type submitted-item">
      <?php print $human_readable_type; ?>
    </div>
  <div class="submitted-author submitted-item">
    <?php print $name; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="submitted-date submitted-item">
    <?php print $date; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="submitted-comments submitted-item">
    <?php print $comment_count; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have added my current code above, Clive. Can you tell me how to restructure it using what you are suggesting? I am still hacking away trying to understand this stuff and need my hand held.

Comment: @Hertzdonit I've updated the answer, have a go with that

Comment: Hi Clive. It's probably best to keep this type of logic out of the templates. I have added an example in my answer.

Comment: @Sam152 Yep you're right...just didn't want to confuse the poor fellow ;)

Comment: Fair enough point. I would imagine learning a framework with limited knowledge of the underlying language would be a daunting task.

Comment: Just needed to add the last endif to your example, otherwise, works perfectly. Thanks guys.

Comment: Sorry about that, it got cut off in the formatting

Answer (score 4):

You can look up this information using `entity_get_info()`. Here is a small code example of how to use this API call:

```
$content_type = 'blog_entry';
$entity_info = entity_get_info('node');
$human_name = $entity_info['bundles'][$content_type]['label'];
```

This call also returns lots of other useful information such as the fields attached to each bundle, but since it loads so much data it's probably better to use the solution Clive posted if you are going to be calling it every page load.

---

Expanding on Clives answer, if you would like to have the type accessible from the node template, add the following code to your `template.php` file inside your current themes file and ensure that you replace MY_THEME with the name of your theme:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars){
    $type_obj = node_type_load($vars['type']);
    $vars['human_type'] = $type_obj->name;
}
```

Then anywhere inside your node templates you can use:

```
<?php print $human_type; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

D7 I use [`node_type_get_name($node->type);`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7.x)